# Why does omniauth require a store for the OpenID provider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, omniauth

OmniAuth is using a store (see [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid)) for the OpenID provider (e.g. `OpenID::Store::Filesystem`) and while setting it up and using it simple, I don't know why is it needed at all.

Does anybody know what's the purpose of this store? Isn't all the necessary information required for OpenID to work sent and received in the involved requests and responses?

Answer (score 2):

There are two tables worth of data that it writes: Nonces and Associations.

Take a look at the /tmp directory in your Rails app. You'll see two directories called nonces and associations that is used by omniauth, in addition to the regular sessions, temp, cache, pids,... directories.

Comment: Why is it needed at all? I removed the store configuration and now those directories are not being created anymore yet it looks like that the app is still working fine.

Comment: If you don't specify a store then Rails just uses a default in memory store.